Dropdown menu value updating but even with setState() the visual is not reflecting it
I'm having a problem with a dropdown menu, to be more specific, a DropdownButtonFormField.
This being a separate widget, being embedded in another widget named CompanyFormThree that is a page in a PageView() on the screen called EditCompanyPage.
I have a function that fetches an address api and fills in all the fields. all form fields that are textfield are working correctly, however the field that is a DropDown has its value updated in setState(), but it does not update the widget on the screen, only if I go back one page and go to that page again.
What i expected and what happened
When I fill in the cep field, it would do the fetch and fill in the fields accordingly, updating all.
In reality, it does update all the textfields values and the value of state/uf but doesn't dont rebuild or update the in screen value, only if I go back and forth between pages.
the dropdown widget
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DefaultDropdown<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final String label;
  final List<T> items;
  final T? initialValue;
  final ValueChanged<T?> onChanged;
  final Color fillColor;
  final double height;

  const DefaultDropdown({
    super.key,
    required this.label,
    required this.items,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.initialValue,
    this.height = 40,
    this.fillColor = const Color(0xFFD5E2E7),
  });

  @override
  DefaultDropdownState<T> createState() => DefaultDropdownState<T>();
}

class DefaultDropdownState<T> extends State<DefaultDropdown<T>> {
  T? _currentValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentValue = widget.initialValue;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          widget.label,
          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 8),
        SizedBox(
          height: widget.height,
          child: DropdownButtonFormField<T>(
            value: _currentValue,
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              setState(() {
                _currentValue = newValue;
                widget.onChanged(newValue);
              });
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              fillColor: widget.fillColor,
              filled: true,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0), // Ajuste o preenchimento
            ),
            isExpanded: true, // Expande o dropdown para preencher o espaço disponível
            items: widget.items.map((T item) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<T>(
                value: item,
                child: Text(
                  item.toString(),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // Adiciona reticências se o texto for muito longo
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
    

The form widget
parameters
  final ValueChanged<String> onUfChanged;
  final String uf;


fetch function

 void _fetchAddressFromCEP(String cep) async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://viacep.com.br/ws/$cep/json/'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);

      if (data['erro'] == null) {
        if(mounted){
          setState(() {
            publicSpaceController.text = data['logradouro'] ?? '';
            neighborhoodController.text = data['bairro'] ?? '';
            cityController.text = data['localidade'] ?? '';
            numberController.text = ''; 
            uf = data['uf'] ?? ''; 
            widget.onUfChanged(uf);


          });
        }
      } else {
        AlertSnackBar.show(context: context, text: "CEP não encontrado.");
      }
    } else {
      AlertSnackBar.show(context: context, text: "Erro ao buscar CEP.");
    }
  }

listener for to call the function when field cep is filled
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    postalCodeController = widget.postalCodeController;
    publicSpaceController = widget.publicSpaceController;
    neighborhoodController = widget.neighborhoodController;
    cityController = widget.cityController;
    numberController = widget.numberController;

    postalCodeController.addListener(() {
      if (postalCodeController.text.length == 9) {
        _fetchAddressFromCEP(postalCodeController.text);
      }
    });
    uf = widget.uf;
  }       

A Textfield that updates correctly and the dropdown
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const Text(
            "Cadastro de Empresa",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 15),
          DefaultTextField(
            type: TextInputType.number,
            mask: postalCodeMask,
            label: "CEP",
            hintText: "",
            controller: widget.postalCodeController,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 15),
          DefaultDropdown(
            items: ufsBrasil,
            label: "UF",
            initialValue: uf != "" ? uf : null,
            onChanged: (newUF) {
              setState(() {
                uf = newUF;
              });
              widget.onUfChanged(newUF.toString());
            },
          ),



The screen
the function the updates the value
  var _state = "";
  void _updateState(String newUF) {
    setState(() {
      print('Updating state from $_state to $newUF'); // Debugging statement

      _state = newUF;
      print('State updated to $_state'); 
    });
  }

the function that fetchs the data
void _fetchCompanyData() async {
...
...
      setState(() {
  _state = data['uf'].toString();
      });
    // ignore: dead_code
    } else {
      AlertSnackBar.show(context: context, text: "Ocorreu um erro ao buscar dados da empresa.",);
    }
  }

it fetchs at the when initiated


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchCompanyData();
  }

where im using the company form
body: 
      PageView(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: _pageController,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [ 
    ... has 3 pages...
    Column(
            children: [
              CompanyFormThree(...textfieldcontrollres... uf: _state, onUfChanged: _updateState),
          




can try any state management tools to update the value.
